# Fail to install Xgboost in R (Windows)

Tags: r

I have installed RTool34 in R and checked with Sys.getenv('PATH').

R version: 3.3.3

For some reasons, I had to install Xgboost 0.4-x on my computer (Windows).
I'm using devtools to install.

Error Message I got:

> make: *** [xgboost_R.o] Error 1 Warning: running command 'make -f
>   "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk"
>   SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)'
>   SHLIB="xgboost.dll" ' had status 2
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xgboost'

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your c++ compiler version as well? you would need greater than 4.8 to install the latest version of it. I am not sure if you meant you are not able to install xgboost version 0.4 itself.